# I want to zoom in and zoom out in ScrollView. How's it possible?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming, uiscrollviewdelegate, pinch

I have a scroll view within one image. I just want to zoom in and zoom out the scroll view. How do I apply zoom in and and zoom out just by doing the pinch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the file http://www.4shared.com/dir/-PGqZEXR/zoominzoomout.html to your project and call it through these functions.

Here `im2` is UIVIEW, and I paste the image on it then passing this through `viewDidLoad` like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadFlowersInView:im2];
    [self.view addSubview:im2];
}
```

Now attach this function like this,

```
- (void) loadFlowersInView: (UIView *) backdrop
{
    NSString *create_button = nil;
    // Add the flowers to random points on the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
            MagPicAppDelegate *appdelegate = (MagPicAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            NSString *whichFlower = appdelegate.imageName;
            UIImage *stemp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"approve.png"];
            DragView *dragger = [[DragView alloc] initWithImage:stemp];
            dragger.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            dragger.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 140.0f);
            [im2 addSubview:dragger];
            [dragger release];
        }
    }
    [self.view  addSubview:im2];
    [im2 release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `maximumZoomScale` and / or `minimumZoomScale` properties of your `UIScrollView` to something else than 1.0 to define how much you want the user to be able to zoom in/out ;)